# Ubuntu System Wifi speed very low

Tags: networking, wireless

In my Internet connection all my devices have normal speed except my Ubuntu system where the speed is one-tenth of the actual speed.

I have been working on this problem since a couple of days but couldn't find any solution.

I had Ubuntu 15.04 and while looking for the solution I updated to 16.04 now. So current version is 16.04.

I am posting my details :

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 12 Jun 2016 14:51 IST +0530

Booted last: 12 Jun 2016 00:00 IST +0530

Script from: 26 May 2016 21:56 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.4.0-24-generic #43-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 8 19:27:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

12:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak] [8086:0083]
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 BGN [8086:1325]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

13:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Dell RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [1028:0447]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 006: ID 413c:8162 Dell Computer Corp. Integrated Touchpad [Synaptics]
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 413c:8161 Dell Computer Corp. Integrated Keyboard
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

iwldvm                233472  0
dell_wmi               16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 dell_wmi
mac80211              737280  1 iwldvm
iwlwifi               200704  1 iwldvm
dell_laptop            20480  0
dcdbas                 16384  1 dell_laptop
cfg80211              565248  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwldvm
wmi                    20480  1 dell_wmi
video                  40960  3 i915,dell_wmi,dell_laptop

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

enp19s0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enp19s0' [IF1]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlp18s0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlp18s0' [IF2]>  
          inet addr:192.168.1.83  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'wlp18s0' [IF2]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:10751 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9889 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:8788689 (8.7 MB)  TX bytes:1938794 (1.9 MB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp19s0   no wireless extensions.

wlp18s0   IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"ASUS"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'ASUS' [AC1]>   
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=14 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=62/70  Signal level=-48 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:2  Invalid misc:5604   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp18s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp18s0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       680     1  0 14:41 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp18s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Intel Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak] (Centrino Wireless-N 1000 BGN)
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         iwlwifi
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.4.0-24-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               39.31.5.1 build 35138
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlp18s0' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:12:00.0/net/wlp18s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlp18s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     ASUS 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       80f59154-aa5c-4bfb-8c8d-5d45a12c9d9e
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     1 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   no
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{5,3}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   80f59154-aa5c-4bfb-8c8d-5d45a12c9d9e | ASUS 1
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[2]:   d0aadc0c-4772-4c75-8339-a0c6d9c1c9b9 | NETGEAR32
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.83/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.1
IP4.DNS[2]:                             202.83.21.24
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        next_server = 0.0.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       expiry = 1465809096
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 86400
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       ip_address = 192.168.1.83
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       routers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.1.255
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       domain_name_servers = 192.168.1.1 202.83.21.24
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       network_number = 192.168.1.0
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.1.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::<IP6 'wlp18s0' [IF2]>/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp19s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp19s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:13:00.0/net/enp19s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

SSID       BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  ACTIVE  * 
ASUS       <MAC 'ASUS' [AC1]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  54 Mbit/s  71      ▂▄▆_  WPA1      yes     * 
NETGEAR32  <MAC 'NETGEAR32' [AN2]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  49      ▂▄__  WPA2      no        

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ASUS]] (600 root)
[connection] id=ASUS | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp18s0' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=ASUS
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/House LANnister]] (600 root)
[connection] id=House LANnister | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp18s0' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=House LANnister
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/MVC]] (600 root)
[connection] id=MVC | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp18s0' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=MVC
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/NETGEAR32]] (600 root)
[connection] id=NETGEAR32 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp18s0' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=NETGEAR32
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ABHIGYAN]] (600 root)
[connection] id=ABHIGYAN | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp18s0' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=ABHIGYAN
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/MBLAZE-AC3633-D3F]] (600 root)
[connection] id=MBLAZE-AC3633-D3F | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp18s0' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=MBLAZE-AC3633-D3F
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/arqam]] (600 root)
[connection] id=arqam | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp18s0' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=arqam
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ASUS 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=ASUS 1 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp18s0' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=ASUS
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Kolkata (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp19s0   no frequency information.

wlp18s0   13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp19s0   Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      1   APs on   Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)

wlp18s0   Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'ASUS' [AC1]>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=65/70  Signal level=-45 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"ASUS"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000022970059a8
                    Extra: Last beacon: 168ms ago
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

##### module infos ######################

[iwldvm]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-24-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/dvm/iwldvm.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi Link AGN driver for Linux
srcversion:     6A40B68AAA6792A5BDEA010
depends:        mac80211,iwlwifi,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-24-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           force_cam:force continuously aware mode (no power saving at all) (bool)

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-24-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     2FFAEED0245CA1D97FE1E44
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-24-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[iwlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-24-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000-13.ucode
srcversion:     651BF6CBF283F6F817B8F3A
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-24-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size_8K:enable 8K amsdu size (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (default: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           d0i3_disable:disable d0i3 functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           lar_disable:disable LAR functionality (default: N) (bool)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-24-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     25A45701AAA64DAC1E47D9D
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-24-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[iwldvm]
force_cam: Y

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 0
amsdu_size_8K: 0
antenna_coupling: 0
bt_coex_active: Y
d0i3_disable: Y
fw_monitor: N
fw_restart: Y
lar_disable: N
led_mode: 0
nvm_file: (null)
power_level: 0
power_save: N
swcrypto: 0
uapsd_disable: Y

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[   21.758988] iwlwifi 0000:12:00.0: loaded firmware version 39.31.5.1 build 35138 op_mode iwldvm
[   22.299184] iwlwifi 0000:12:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG disabled
[   22.299188] iwlwifi 0000:12:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUGFS enabled
[   22.299189] iwlwifi 0000:12:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TRACING enabled
[   22.299193] iwlwifi 0000:12:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 1000 BGN, REV=0x6C
[   22.299279] iwlwifi 0000:12:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled
[   24.655295] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-agn-rs'
[   24.656353] iwlwifi 0000:12:00.0 wlp18s0: renamed from wlan0
[   51.866639] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp18s0: link is not ready
[   51.866773] iwlwifi 0000:12:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled (repeated 2 times)
[   51.874461] iwlwifi 0000:12:00.0: Radio type=0x0-0x0-0x3
[   51.910411] iwlwifi 0000:12:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled (repeated 2 times)
[   51.918094] iwlwifi 0000:12:00.0: Radio type=0x0-0x0-0x3
[   51.947370] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp18s0: link is not ready
[   51.951548] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp19s0: link is not ready
[   51.959184] r8169 0000:13:00.0 enp19s0: link down
[   51.959222] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp19s0: link is not ready
[   59.616827] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp18s0: link is not ready
[   60.022540] wlp18s0: authenticate with <MAC 'ASUS' [AC1]>
[   60.026788] wlp18s0: send auth to <MAC 'ASUS' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[   60.029585] wlp18s0: authenticated
[   60.029813] iwlwifi 0000:12:00.0 wlp18s0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[   60.029818] wlp18s0: waiting for beacon from <MAC 'ASUS' [AC1]>
[   60.070276] wlp18s0: associate with <MAC 'ASUS' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[   60.073256] wlp18s0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'ASUS' [AC1]> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[   60.077332] wlp18s0: associated
[   60.077408] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp18s0: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```